# How can I manipulate an object's structure into a 'dot notation'-style array

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am working on a project using Meteor, which connects to an external API with Mongoose (With Meteor.HTTP). I have nested objects whose source data looks like this:

```
{name: "asdasd", active: true, status: Object, domain: "asdas", category: "1"…}
```

I need to POST/PUT the data in this format:

```
{
  active: true,
  category: "1",
  contact.companyName: "asd",
  contact.email: "asd",
  contact.managerName: "asd",
  contact.phone: "asd",
  domain: "asdasd",
  name: "asjdnas",
  ImagePaths: ["asdasdad","asdasdAsd"],
}
```

**without** nested style objects, or any kind of:

```
ImagePaths[0] : asdasdad,
ImagePaths[1] : asdasdad

sites: 
   0: "565f1c7da35dcaa718713f4f"
```

etc. I found this code (by @rhalff)

```
var dotize = dotize || {};

dotize.parse = function(jsonobj, prefix) {
  var newobj = {};
  function recurse(o, p) {
    for (var f in o)
    {
      var pre = (p === undefined ? '' : p + ".");
      if (o[f] && typeof o[f] === "object"){
        newobj = recurse(o[f], pre + f);
      } else {
        newobj[pre + f] = o[f];
      }
    }
    return newobj;
  }
  return recurse(jsonobj, prefix);
};
```

But I'm still having problems with arrays. They are appearing like this:

```
  Paths.0: "asdkmalksmdasd",
  Paths.1: "asdasdad",
```

What I need is this:

```
Paths:["asdkmalksmdasd","asdasdad"];
```

You can play it here on jsbin: https://jsbin.com/kadivewoti/edit?js,console

How can I achieve this?

Comment: And it is the `ImagePaths` property that is causing you the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I added one `if-statement` to the code:

```
var dotize = dotize || {};

dotize.parse = function(jsonobj, prefix) {
  var newobj = {};
  function recurse(o, p) {
    for (var f in o)
    {
      var pre = (p === undefined ? '' : p + ".");
      if(o[f] && o[f].length){
        newobj[f] = o[f];
      }
      else if (o[f] && typeof o[f] === "object"){
        newobj = recurse(o[f], pre + f);
      } 
      else {
        newobj[pre + f] = o[f];
      }
    }
    return newobj;
  }
  return recurse(jsonobj, prefix);
};

var mydata = '{"name":"asjdnas","active":true,"status":{"pending":true,"comment":"asdasd"},"domain":"asdasd","category":"1","contact":{"companyName":"asd","managerName":"asd","phone":"asd","email":"asd"},"server":{"os":"akjsdn"},"Paths":["asdkmalksmdasd","asdasdad"]}';


mydata = JSON.parse(mydata);
mydata = dotize.parse(mydata);
console.log(mydata);
```

Namely

```
if(o[f] && o[f].length){
    newobj[f] = o[f];
}
```

Comment: `if( Object.prototype.toString.call( o[f] ) === '[object Array]' )`